# Wavelet Transform - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to learn how does the Wavelet transform works from a practical point of view. I have read the theory regarding it and I think that I have understood the main idea behind it, but I would like to have some practice with it.

Can you please recommend me some tutorial and some data which I can use for learning the Wavelet Transform by using Matlab environment?

I tried to search for audio signal or practical tutorial on which I can work on but I had no results.

Comment: I think this question is suited for: [DSP](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Mathworks site has some information on their [wavelet toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/wavelet/) and some simple examples of [continuous 1D wavelet transforms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/wavelet/ref/cwt.html) and [discrete 2D wavelet transforms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html).

Since you have studied and understood the theory behind wavelet transforms, the best way to learn is to go through the source code for various algorithms that have been used by others. For starters looking at the *core* of the various functions provided in the toolbox above (just enter `type functionname` at the command line in MATLAB. Unless if it's a built-in function, you'll see the file contents). By core of the function, I mean the main algorithm without all the various input checks that are common.

The [Wavelab](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~wavelab/) toolbox from Stanford university is also a good resource to learn from (and later use in your applications when you're comfortable with it).

Lastly, [this is a resource](http://www-math.bgsu.edu/z/wavelets/) I found by Googling and it looks like they have some examples that you can try out.